# MediaPlayerViewController rotates into view before play

Tags: iphone, xcode, ipad

My MediaPlayerViewController developed this funny thing of rotating into view!  My whole app is landscape based, but the MediaPlayerViewController seems to rotate from portrait to landscape and when finished the previous view would then also rotate from portrait into its original landscape orientation.  This will not happen in a small test app.  Only when the app becomes complicated. I have tried preloading the movie, doesn't help, i have tried didRotatefromInterfaceOrientation, nothing.  I have my supported orientations set and to return UIInterfaceOrientationIsLandscape.  My code for the movie if that might help:

```
NSString *moviePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"BearA-least" ofType:@"mov"];
NSURL *movieURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:moviePath];
MPMoviePlayerViewController *moviePlayer = [[MPMoviePlayerViewController alloc] initWithContentURL:movieURL];
[self presentModalViewController:moviePlayer animated:NO];
moviePlayer.moviePlayer.controlStyle = MPMovieControlStyleNone;
[moviePlayer.moviePlayer play];
```

I'm new to developing and have been struggling with this problem for a while.  Any input would be greatly appreciated.  I've seen people having similar problems with views rotating.

Answer (score 0):

As I see, you're using `MediaPlayerViewController` and presenting it using `presentModalViewController`

1. MoviePlayerViewControllers are usually displayed using `[self presentMoviePlayerViewControllerAnimated:(PlayerViewController)]`
2. As I can see, you're preventing your user from controlling the playback -> `MPMovieControlStyleNone`
3. Hint: You might also want to set the `movieSourceType` property on your `MoviePlayerController`.

For controlling the orientation in a way as you're trying to achieve, I would suggest you to subclass `MPMoviePlayerViewController` and listen for notifications sent by the MPMoviePlayer on the various movie playback events.

Comment: Hi Shaharyar  Thanks you so much for getting back to me.  I've been through your reply backwards and forwards but still no luck.  I tried Animated as NO to stop it from rotating, that wasn't my problem.  I didn't want the viewer to control the playback, but that makes no difference either.  Adding the player as a subview is giving me a blank screen every time!  What is that about?  Also not sure what you mean about my movieSourceType property.  Thanks again for helping.